# SecCodeCopySigningInformation generates strange errors

Tags: swift, macos, logging, digital-signature, swift5

I have some code to check code signatures on macOS:

```
// Get a code reference.
var codeOpt: SecCode? = nil
var err = SecCodeCopyGuestWithAttributes(nil, [kSecGuestAttributeAudit : sourceAppAuditToken] as NSDictionary, [], &codeOpt)
guard err == errSecSuccess, let code = codeOpt else {
    return nil
}

// Convert that to a static code.
var staticCodeOpt: SecStaticCode? = nil
err = SecCodeCopyStaticCode(code, [] , &staticCodeOpt)
guard err == errSecSuccess, let staticCode = staticCodeOpt else {
    return nil
}

// Get code signing information about that.
var infoOpt: CFDictionary? = nil
// this generates MacOS error: -25337 and CSSM Exception: -2147414013 CSSMERR_DL_MDS_ERROR
err = SecCodeCopySigningInformation(staticCode, SecCSFlags(rawValue: kSecCSInternalInformation ), &infoOpt) 
guard err == errSecSuccess, let info = infoOpt as? [String:Any] else {
    return nil
}
```

The call to `SecCodeCopySigningInformation` generates the following errors on the system's log :

> MacOS error: -25337
>
> CSSM Exception: -2147414013 CSSMERR_DL_MDS_ERROR

Does anyone know why these errors are there? As far as I can tell, my code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

before invoking SecCodeCopySigningInformation you should create again your staticCode, e.g.

```
NSURL               *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
CFURLRef            path = (__bridge CFURLRef)url;

SecStaticCodeRef    codeRef;
SecStaticCodeCreateWithPath(path, kSecCSDefaultFlags, &codeRef);
```

Also use these flags

```
SecCSFlags      flags = kSecCSInternalInformation;
CFDictionaryRef signingInfo = nil;
OSStatus        status = SecCodeCopySigningInformation(codeRef, flags, &signingInfo);
```